# Uncaught reference error in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reference

I keep getting an Uncaught Reference error in the following script.  Firebug keeps telling me that "Initialize" is not defined when I try to call it onLoad.  Could someone please help me spot my mistake? I've been looking at this for hours and can't seem to find it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script LANGUAGE="text/javascript">
var thePest

function VirtualHamster(state, petaction, petsound) {
    this.state = state
    this.petaction = petaction
    this.petsound = petsound
}

function Initialize() {
    thePest = new VirtualHamster("Sleeping", "", "Zzzzzzzz……")
    Display(thePest)
    setTimeout("Simulate(thePest)", 1000)
}

function Display(pest) {
    var state = pest.state
    if (state == "Excited") {
        pest.petaction = ""
        pest.petsound = "Eep eep!"
    } else if (state == "Sleeping") {
        pest.petaction = ""
        pest.petsound = "Zzzzzzzz……"
    } else if (state == "Bored") {
        pest.petsound = ""
        pest.petaction = "Stare at Owner"
    } else if (state == "Thirsty") {
        pest.petsound = ""
        pest.petaction = "Stick tongue out"
    } else if (state == "Hungry") {
        pest.petsound = ""
        pest.petaction = "Bite!!"
    } else {
        pest.petaction = "Error - unknown state"
        pest.petsound = "Oh No!"
    }

    document.getElementById("state").value = pest.state
    document.getElementById("petaction").value = pest.petaction
    document.getElementById("petsound").value = pest.petsound
}

function Scratch(pest) {
    var state = pest.state.value
    if (state == "Sleeping") {
        pest.state.value = "Excited"
    }
    Display(pest)
}

function Feed(pest) {
    var state = pest.state.value
    if (state == "Hungry") {
        pest.state.value = "Thirsty"
    }
    Display(pest)
}

function Simulate(pest) {
    var state = pest.state.value
    var n = Math.random()
    if (state == "Excited" && n < 0.2) {
        pest.state = "Bored"
    } else if (state == "Bored" && n < 0.25) {
        pest.state = "Hungry"
    } else if (state == "Thirsty" && n < 0.9) {
        pest.state = "Sleeping"
    }
    Display(pest)
    setTimeout("Simulate(thePest)", 1000)
}
</script>             
<body bgcolor="gold" onLoad="Initialize()">
<h1><center>Larry: The Virtual Hamster!</h1></center>
<center><img src="sleeping.jpg"></center>
<form NAME="pest">
<center><b>Pest Sound:</b> <input type=text name=petsound size=20 maxlength=30 /> </center><br>
<center><b>Pest Action:</b> <input type=text name=petaction size=20 maxlength=30 /></center> <br>
<center><b>The Pests state is:</b> <input type=text name=state size=20 maxlength=30 /></center> <br>
<center><input type="button" name="Scratch" value="Scratch Back"onClick="Scratch(thePest)"></center>
<center><input type="button" name="Feed" value="Feed the Hamster"onClick="Feed(thePest)"></center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably have syntax errors.

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: How should I format the setTimeout otherwise? @SLaks

Comment: @user3034460 `setTimeout(function(){Simulate(thePest);}, 1000)`

Comment: try removing `LANGUAGE="text/javascript"` from your `<script>` tag, or change it to `type="text/javascript"`

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure to use commas (,) and semicolons (;) correctly to end lines.  it looks like you're going to be having issues beginning with `var thePest`...at a glance, it looks like thePest isn't being used to define the VirtualHamster method so you will need a comma after thePest, for example.

make sure you are formatting correctly or else your definitions will not align correctly, so to speak. this is being discussed as optional though.

either way, you'll also want to pass the reference to Simulate in the setTimeout as well. just say `setTimeout(Simulate, 1000)` and instead of using pest inside of Simulate, use the global thePest

just noticed that you also need to add the appropriate ID attributes to your input tags.

`<input type=text name=petsound size=20 maxlength=30 />` becomes `<input id="petsound" type=text name=petsound size=20 maxlength=30 />`

working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ykL7g/7/

Comment: Semicolons are optional. `var thePest` is perfectly fine.

Comment: So after defining the variable "thePest" I should include a comma?

Comment: i agree, but with no separator between thePest and the VirtualHamster function would either need =, ,, or ; after thePest to keep the definitions separated. most likely the ;

Comment: @user3034460: It would be better, but it is not required. If you copy your code to http://jshint.com, you will see that here is no syntax error.

Comment: No, it's not required. JavaScript inserts semicolons automatically. See, it works all fine: http://jsfiddle.net/PpmCb/.

Comment: either way, you'll also want to pass the reference to Simulate in the setTimeout as well.  just say `setTimeout(Simulate, 1000)` and instead of using pest inside of Simulate, use the global thePest

Comment: `function Initialize()
{
thePest = new VirtualHamster("Sleeping","","Zzzzzzzz……")
Display(thePest)
setTimeout(Simulate(thePest),1000)
}`

Comment: @user3034460: `setTimeout(Simulate(thePest),1000)` passes the return value of calling `Simulate` to `setTimeout`.

Comment: So how should I modifiy it?

Comment: `setTimeout(Simulate, 1000)` and inside of Simulate, don't use `pest` because it won't be passed in; you will need to use `thePest`

Comment: also, if you wanted to keep Simulate the same, you could always just say `setTimeout(function(){Simulate(thePest)}, 1000)`

Comment: Ok, I see now! Would you know of anything else that would cause it to be undefined, because it is still giving me that error.

Comment: i still think you should add a `;` after `var thePest`.  it's saying Initialize is still undefined, right?

Comment: Now that I changed `LANGUAGE="text/javascript"` to `type="text/javascript"` it is throwing an Uncaught TypeError.  It says "Cannot set property 'value' of null" in line 50.

Comment: is it because of the pest.state.value call? shouldn't they just be pest.state?

Comment: It is just pest.state.

Comment: So you're saying that it should just be `document.getElementById("state")= pest.state` instead of `document.getElementById("state").value= pest.state`right?

Comment: naw, in Scratch, Feed, and Simulate, the first line should read `var state = pest.state` if i'm reading this correctly

Comment: i'm playing in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ykL7g/ in case anyone else wants a test bed

Comment: added more to my answer...your latest error is because you need to set the ID attribute on the elements your are trying to get(ElementById)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the deprecated attribute `language` and should be using `type`

I put the troublesome code over to codepen and I got the same error.

Example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JjFEA

But if I changed

```
<script LANGUAGE="text/javascript">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

I was able to run `Initialize()`

Example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/djcJH

The `language` attribute is deprecated and isn't recommended to use, `type` should be used instead.
More information [ [script language attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-language) ]